# centralized authenticaion with OpenLDAP for Red Hat Linux with slapd.conf configuration

Tags: openldap

I am currenty working on to setup a centralized authenticaion with OpenLDAP for Red Hat Linux .

Objective - Setup a Centralized OpenLDAP authentication for Red Hat Linux Servers where client can connect with ssh , user administration can be done from one server.

Please I am not looking for rpm or yum installation no cn=config. I want to configure with slapd.conf and ldap.conf

```
tar -xvf db-4.7.25.NC.tar.gz

   ls -ltr

   cp patch.4.7.25.1 patch.4.7.25.2 patch.4.7.25.3 patch.4.7.25.4 db-4.7.25.NC

   cd db-4.7.25.NC

   patch -p0 patch.4.7.25.1

   patch -p0 < patch.4.7.25.1

   patch -p0 < patch.4.7.25.2

   patch -p0 < patch.4.7.25.3

   patch -p0 < patch.4.7.25.4

   cd build_unix/

   ./dist/configure

    make

    make install

   export CPPFLAGS="-I/usr/local/BerkeleyDB.4.7/include"

   export LDFLAGS="-L/usr/local/BerkeleyDB.4.7/lib"

   export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/opt/db-4.7.25.NC/build_unix/.libs

   vi /etc/profile

   source /etc/profile
```

---

```
   cd /opt/

   tar -xvzf openldap-2.4.23.tgz

   openldap-2.4.23

./configure  --with-tls --enable-accesslog --enable-auditlog --enable-dyngroup --enable-dynlist --enable-ppolicy --enable-bdb --enable-syslog --with-cyrus-sasl --with-threads --enable-crypt=yes --enable-ldap=yes --enable-proxycache=yes   

 make depend

make

make test

make install
```

---

```
   vi /usr/local/etc/openldap/slapd.conf

 slappasswd

my slapd.conf ---------------

database     bdb

suffix       "dc=exa,dc=com"

rootdn       "cn=Manager,dc=exa,dc=com"

rootpw {SSHA}PxEhMMYJvFRqT3L4fYYCmevrt22zYeDS

directory     /usr/local/var/openldap-data

======================================================

root objects for the LDAP database

cat exa.ldif

dn: dc=exa,dc=sea

dc: exa

description: Root LDAP entry for exa.sea

objectClass: dcObject

objectClass: organizationalUnit


dn: ou=People,dc=exa,dc=com

ou: People

description: All people in organisation

objectClass: organizationalUnit
```

I have added the entries successfully and can search the database but when I am trying to change password it is giving error message (Result: No such object (32) )

```
**cn: uid=naveen,ou=People,dc=exa,dc=com

uid: naveen

cn: naveen

objectClass: account

objectClass: posixAccount

objectClass: top

objectClass: shadowAccount

userPassword: {crypt}$1$SBo8cFfd$Nqc9yqobHxwiom/0BLPnf.

shadowLastChange: 12502

shadowMax: 99999

shadowWarning: 7

loginShell: /bin/bash

uidNumber: 2000

gidNumber: 2000

homeDirectory: /home/naveen**


===============================================
[root@localhost bob]# ldappasswd -vx -D "cn=Manager,dc=exa,dc=com" -W -
S "uid=naveen,ou=People,dc=exa,dc=com"

New password:

Re-enter new password:

ldap_initialize( <DEFAULT> )

Enter LDAP Password:

Result: No such object (32)
```

Could anyone suggest me a better way to do OpenLDAP Authenticaiton for Red Hat Linux with slapd.conf and client configuration.

client configuration -

authconfig-tui

ldap.conf slapd.conf

=======================================================================================

I solved the ldappasswd issue.

```
[root@localhost opt]# ldappasswd -vx -D "cn=Manager,dc=exa,dc=com" -W -S "cn=John Smith,ou=People,dc=exa,dc=com" 
New password: 
Re-enter new password: ldap_initialize( ) 
Enter LDAP Password: 
Result: Success (0) 
[root@localhost opt]#
```

Please advise me better way to authenticate Clients using OpenLDAP thanks.

Thanks in advance Naveen

Answer (score 2):

You should configure `pam` and `nss-pam-ldapd` on the client, to allow the LDAP directory servers to be used as a primary source of name service information for users, hosts, groups, and other.

Now all depends wich client you have, for [fedora](http://docs.fedoraproject.org/en-US/Fedora/15/html/Deployment_Guide/ch-Directory_Servers.html#s2-ldap-pam) and [rhel](https://access.redhat.com/knowledge/docs/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux/6/pdf/Deployment_Guide/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux-6-Deployment_Guide-en-US.pdf) the "*Deployment Guide*" is a good resource.

Anyway you can configure them with `system-config-authentication` or `authconfig`      `authconfig-tui`.

this command works to configure my fedora 19 machine against my openLdap directory:

`authconfig --updateall --passalgo=md5 --enableldap --enableldapauth --ldapserver=myserver.mydomain --ldapbasedn=dc=mycompany --enableldaptls --enableldapstarttls --ldaploadcacert=http://myserver.mydomain/server.pem`

For other distros you must googling a bit.

Answer (score 2):

Your question is pretty badly formed, Naveen.  It seems like you know what you want to do, but you haven't really thought through (or researched) how to accomplish it.

The general outline for setting up LDAP-based authentication is:

1. **Decide on a directory structure**
   You need to figure out what your LDAP directory will look like.
   Think like an AD deployment (much as it pains me to say such things).
2. **Install an LDAP server**
   You should use Yum/Apt/whatever your OS standard way of installing stuff is for this part.
   There's no sense in making work for yourself by building it from source unless you have to.
3. **Add the RFC 2307 schema, and anything else you need**
   RFC 2307 is the minimum. You probably also want to add the sudo schema if you use sudo, and the OpenSSH LDAP Public Keys schema if you use SSH.
4. **Configure your OS**
   Enable the OpenSSH-LPK (LDAP Public Keys) patch if you intend to use it.
   Install pam_ldap/nss_ldap (or pam_ldapd) and add LDAP to your `nsswitch.conf` file.
5. **Populate your LDAP Directory**
   Add a couple of users and groups.
6. **Test** and **Profit**.

---

There are a number of tutorials which will help you out if you google around.
There are also [some words from RedHat](http://docs.redhat.com/docs/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux/6/html/Deployment_Guide/ch-Configuring_Authentication.html) on the subject, though I can't vouch for their accuracy as I don't run RedHat in my environment.

Answer (score 0):

This should help you -- http://www.gentoo.org/doc/en/ldap-howto.xml

Comment: Welcome to Server Fault! We really do prefer that answers contain content not pointers to content. Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.